# How to Hash/checksum of string

Tags: vb.net, hash, checksum

So I have a generator that creates a 26 hexadecimal character string that has a balance of ones and zeros when converted to binary. Actually 26.5.the first half of the 27th characters binary value  is stored in a buf. and the last half is used to make the first 106 bits nice and even. Or should at least. How would I use the binary remnants in the buf to generate the  the 27th char and to make the last 22 bits into a hash/checksum for the first 106? below is my generator.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim bin As New StringBuilder()
    Dim buf As Integer = 0, bufLen As Integer = 0, left As Integer = 53
    For i As Integer = 106 To 0 Step -1
        buf <<= 1
        If rnd.[Next](i) < left Then
            buf += 1
            left -= 1
        End If
        If System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(bufLen) = 4 Then
            bin.Append("0123456789abcdef"(buf))
            bufLen = 0
            buf = 0
        End If
    Next
    Dim b As String = bin.ToString()

    TextBox1.Text = (b)
```

How would I add on to this completing the process?

Answer (score 0):

You've got 106 to 0 step -1, which means 107 iterations creating 26 hex digits with ***three*** further bits in `buf` (though the last one's guaranteed to be 0)... you might as well make it 108 and have it add an extra hex digit to `bin` - it doesn't matter that it's also 0, then you can apply any >=22 bit hash/checksum algo you like to the data in `bin` and append the hash/checksum value - you obviously know how to slice the least significant 4 bits off the left, generate the hex digit, and rotate - the last time you can AND with 3 and OR or XOR the value over the final hex digit you generated - setting the two trailing 0s added above.  Googling "VB checksum" turns up lots of example code.  If you get stuck, post your code and specific problem.

Separately, I don't know VB so maybe there's some weird reason, but I can't imagine why you're using what appears to be a threadsafe increment for a local variable which I'd assume in on the executing thread's stack and inaccessible to other threads?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. will do more research now. I am very new to .net let alone hashing and checksums. I had no idea what to google lol. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know your needs re security vs obfuscation/randomness, but something like [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) seems a good place to start....